# B table display html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I have this code :

```
{
    key: 'synch',
    label: this.$t('Synch'),
    formatter: value => {
       return value;
    }
},
```

With api data :

```
this.items.map(element => {
    element.synchro =
       `<span class="badge p-2 badge-warning">
            <b-icon icon="${element.coptis_sync ? 'check' : 'cancel'}" font-scale="1" variant="muted">
            </b-icon>
        </span>`
 });
```

Display is like this :

[image]

Is possible somehow in formatter to transform in html?

Comment: have you tried writing `v-html="..."` in your template area?

Comment: where exactly ???

Comment: How are you rendering it inside the template?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I want to send it like this, don't know if is the best way

Comment: to send it where?

Comment: @klsdskldsd - here is an explanation how to use [the v-html directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

Comment: I mean to put here : ` <b-table :items="items"`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I tried like this too : `formatter: value => {
                        return `<span v-html="${value}"></span>`;
                    }`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [scoped-field-slots](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#scoped-field-slots) :

```
<b-table :items="items" >
  <!-- A custom formatted column -->
      <template #cell(sync)="data">
      <span class="badge p-2 badge-warning">
            <b-icon :icon="data.item.coptis_sync ? 'check' : 'cancel'" font-scale="1" variant="muted">
            </b-icon>
        </span>
      </template>

</b-table>
```

Comment: I get the point, but for example if I will have 10 elements besides `synch` with html content. I will have some duplications. No other solution @Boussadjra Brahim ?

Comment: I don't understand your issue

Comment: If I will have `synch1, synch2, synch3,synch4,synch5,synch6,synch7,synch8, synch9,synch10` that means I will have 10 times  `<template #cell(sync)="data">
      <span class="badge p-2 badge-warning">
            <b-icon :icon="data.item.coptis_sync ? 'check' : 'cancel'" font-scale="1" variant="muted">
            </b-icon>
        </span>
      </template>` with only cell change

Comment: you understand the issue ?

Comment: No, please share the a snippet from the fields and items properties

Comment: @klsdskldsd [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67521512/381282)